# Can't deploy EAR to Google App Engine 1.9.4

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudbees

I'm having troubles deploying a Google App Engine EAR application from Cloudbees.  The application is built using 1.9.4.  The application structure is similar to this project: https://github.com/deege/gae-rest-skeleton  The main difference is I have more than just one module.

[image]

The problem I'm running into is how to configure the deployment.  I have the "Post steps | Deploy Applications | Google App Engine (Java)" set up as the video from their site, but the configuration is expecting a WAR directory structure in the Fixed Directory section.

[image]

It's looking for a directory where a WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml file exists.  I can point the configuration to the front end's directory where this does exist (and was doing that until I added more modules), but then it only deploys the front end.  None of the other WARs are deployed.

I think it *should* be looking for the META-INF/appengine-application.xml file in the ear directory, since this describes the whole application (front ends and supporting modules).

Is there something I'm missing with the configuration?  Do I need to deploy each module (WAR) separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our deployer plugin was written before GAE added support for EARs. If ignoring the form validation and just entering the configuration that you *know* should work doesn't work then open a ticket.

I will be investigating and adding the extra form validation to the plugin at my next review window for the plugin, but an interim workaround of just ignoring any displayed errors *should* work

## update

I have updated the app engine deployer plugin. Upgrading to version 3.0 or newer will allow you to deploy EAR exploded archives

Comment: I opened a ticket.  I can ignore field validation, but it appends WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml to anything I put in there.